# Python - not enough values to unpack from tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

Following the Tensorflow [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv).

```
TRAIN_DATA_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv"
LABEL_COLUMN_TRAIN = 'Survived'
train_file_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file("train.csv", TRAIN_DATA_URL)
SELECT_COLUMNS = ['Survived', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Fare']
DEFAULTS = [0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
temp_dataset = get_dataset(
    train_file_path, 
    label_column_name=LABEL_COLUMN_TRAIN, 
    select_columns=SELECT_COLUMNS,
    column_defaults=DEFAULTS
)


def pack(features, label):
  return tf.stack(list(features.values()), axis=-1), label

packed_dataset = temp_dataset.map(pack)
for features, labels in packed_dataset.take(1):
  print(features.numpy())
  print(labels.numpy())
```

This shows below.

```
[[ 0.     1.    15.5  ]
 [30.     3.    21.   ]
 [ 0.     0.     7.896]
 [21.     0.     8.663]
 [39.     0.     7.925]]
[0 1 0 0 0]
```

## Question

Please help understand the cause of the error.

I believe packed_dataset.take(1) returns a tuple of two element.

```
packed_dataset.take(1)
<TakeDataset shapes: ((None, 3), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>
```

However, below causes the error.

```
(features, labels) = packed_dataset.take(1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-dceb31d47f78> in <module>
----> 1 features, labels = packed_dataset.take(1)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

the function 
`pack(feature, labels)` 
require 2 arguments, while function call 
`for features, labels in packed_dataset.take(1)`
passes only one argument with the value 1, it should expect
`for features, labels in packed_dataset.take(1, ?)`

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Could you provide a code that works?